# How to Insert null from TextBox to integer Field

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have a text box and datetime where can i enter an integer . I wish to store this in a SQL Server Database. If I enter nothing then I would store `NULL`.
However if the text box is left blank, I get an error Input string was not in a correct format.

How can I work around this, and get the null into the db?

The code is as follows:

```
public void Add_ItemSeasonalPrices(string ItemCode, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate, decimal WholeSaleForFirstUnit, decimal WholeSaleForSecondUnit, decimal WholeSaleForThirdUnit,
        decimal HalfWholeSaleForFirstUnit, decimal HalfWholeSaleForSecondUnit, decimal HalfWholeSaleForThirdUnit,
        decimal DistributorForFirstUnit, decimal DistributorForSecondUnitt)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DAL.open();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[22];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ItemCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25);
        param[0].Value = ItemCode;

        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[1].Value = FromDate;


        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[2].Value = ToDate;


        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@WholeSaleForFirstUnit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[3].Value = WholeSaleForFirstUnit;


        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@WholeSaleForSecondUnit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[4].Value = WholeSaleForSecondUnit;


        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@WholeSaleForThirdUnit ", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[5].Value = WholeSaleForThirdUnit;

        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@HalfWholeSaleForFirstUnit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[6].Value = HalfWholeSaleForFirstUnit;


        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@HalfWholeSaleForSecondUnit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[7].Value = HalfWholeSaleForSecondUnit;


        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@HalfWholeSaleForThirdUnit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[8].Value = HalfWholeSaleForThirdUnit;


        param[9] = new SqlParameter("@DistributorForFirstUnit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[9].Value = DistributorForFirstUnit;


        param[10] = new SqlParameter("@DistributorForSecondUnit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[10].Value = DistributorForSecondUnit;


        DAL.ExecuteCommand("Add_ItemSeasonalPrices", param);
        DAL.close();
    }
```

and this Code in btnSave

```
Item.Add_ItemSeasonalPrices(txt_ItemCode.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_WholeSaleForFirstUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_WholeSaleForSecondUnit.Text),
                                            Convert.ToDecimal(txt_WholeSaleForThirdUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_HalfWholeSaleForFirstUnit.Text),
                                            Convert.ToDecimal(txt_HalfWholeSaleForSecondUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_HalfWholeSaleForThirdUnit.Text),
                                            Convert.ToDecimal(txt_DistributorForFirstUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_DistributorForSecondUnit.Text));
```

and this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemSeasonalPrices](
[ItemCode] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[FromDate] [date] NULL,
[ToDate] [date] NULL,
[WholeSaleForFirstUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[WholeSaleForSecondUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[WholeSaleForThirdUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[HalfWholeSaleForFirstUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[HalfWholeSaleForSecondUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[HalfWholeSaleForThirdUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[DistributorForFirstUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[DistributorForSecondUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[DistributorForThirdUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[ExportForFirstUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[ExportForSecondUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[ExportForThirdUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[RetailForFirstUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[RetailForSecondUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[RetailForThirdUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[EndUserForFirstUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[EndUserForSecondUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[EndUserForThirdUnit] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[PriceDefault] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: you can use Attribute Validation

Comment: You should simplify your code and be to-the-point. Many people won't bother themselves to read all this code.

Answer (score 0):

You receive the `Format Exception` (Input string was not in correct format) because at least one of your text boxes did not contain a valid decimal.

You could use [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `Convert.ToDecimal` for all of your variables.

```
decimal exportForFirstUnit;
decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out exportForFirstUnit);
```

Alternatively you could have to put some validation on these fields and at least check if the textbox contains a value.

Another issue is that your logic is flawed.  Consider these lines in your code:

```
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
param[1].Value = FromDate;
param[1].Value = DBNull.Value;

param[2] = new SqlParameter("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
param[2].Value = ToDate;
param[2].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

You correctly declare `FromDate` and `ToDate` and then set the SQL parameter up to have the values from the textbox, you then ovveride this value with `NULL`, therefore for each `INSERT` statement you execute your table will always contain no data instead of the data the user has entered via your form.

As an additional note your `Add_ItemSeasonalPrices` seems to take in a lot of parameters, it may be best to have this in a class (SeasonalItems) which will be much easier to work with.

```
public class SeasonalItems
{
    public decimal WholeSaleForFirstUnit { get; set; }
    public decimal WholeSaleForSecondUnit { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use this as a parameter to the method, as shown below:

```
public void AddItemSeasonalPrices(SeasonalItems items)
{

}
```

You could extend the class further to accomodate more units as the application grows, but I believe this would suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

Many places you should consider modifying your code.

Modify `Add_ItemSeasonalPrices` definition to accept `nullable` `DateTime` value.

```
public void Add_ItemSeasonalPrices(string ItemCode, DateTime? FromDate, DateTime? ToDate, decimal WholeSaleForFirstUnit, decimal WholeSaleForSecondUnit, decimal WholeSaleForThirdUnit,
        decimal HalfWholeSaleForFirstUnit, decimal HalfWholeSaleForSecondUnit, decimal HalfWholeSaleForThirdUnit,
        decimal DistributorForFirstUnit, decimal DistributorForSecondUnit,  decimal DistributorForThirdUnit,
        decimal ExportForFirstUnit, decimal ExportForSecondUnit, decimal ExportForThirdUnit,
        decimal RetailForFirstUnit, decimal RetailForSecondUnit, decimal RetailForThirdUnit, 
        decimal EndUserForFirstUnit, decimal EndUserForSecondUnit, decimal EndUserForThirdUnit, int PriceDefault)
    {
       .....
    }
```

And in `btn_save`, add validation before converting to `DateTime`

```
Item.Add_ItemSeasonalPrices(txt_ItemCode.Text, 

                            string.IsNullOrEmpty(FromDate.Text)? null: Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate.Text), 
                            string.IsNullOrEmpty(ToDate.Text)? null: Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_WholeSaleForFirstUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_WholeSaleForSecondUnit.Text),
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(txt_WholeSaleForThirdUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_HalfWholeSaleForFirstUnit.Text),
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(txt_HalfWholeSaleForSecondUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_HalfWholeSaleForThirdUnit.Text),
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(txt_DistributorForFirstUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_DistributorForSecondUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_DistributorForThirdUnit.Text),
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(txt_ExportForFirstUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_ExportForSecondUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_ExportForThirdUnit.Text),
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(txt_RetailForFirstUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_RetailForSecondUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_RetailForThirdUnit.Text),
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(txt_EndUserForFirstUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_EndUserForSecondUnit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_EndUserForThirdUnit.Text),
                                                PriceDefault);
```

And last but not least, code is overriding every `parameter` value.

```
    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    param[1].Value = FromDate.HasValue? FromDate.Value : DBNull.Value;
    //param[1].Value = DBNull.Value;

    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    param[2].Value = ToDate.HasValue? ToDate.Value : DBNull.Value;
    //param[2].Value = DBNull.Value;
```